# penalizing negative skewness by linking $U(\mu)$ and $U(\Sigma)$

Tags: financial-engineering, portfolio-management

Consider $U_1(\mu,\Sigma)$ and $U_2(\mu,\Sigma)$, where $U_1(\mu, \cdot) = U_2(\mu, \cdot)$, $U_1(\cdot, \Sigma) = U_2(\cdot, \Sigma)$ such that

\begin{equation*}
arg\inf\limits_{\mu \in U_1(\mu, \cdot), \Sigma \in U_1(\cdot, \Sigma)} \left(w^T \mu – \alpha w^T \Sigma w \right)
\equiv arg\inf\limits_{\mu \in U_2(\mu, \cdot), \Sigma \in U_2(\cdot, \Sigma)} \left(w^T \mu – \alpha w^T \Sigma w\right)
\end{equation*}

Solutions for inner problems are the same

$(\mu, \Sigma)$ from $U_1$ are positively related ($\Sigma \uparrow$ as $\mu \uparrow \Rightarrow$ positively skewed)

$(\mu, \Sigma)$ from $U_2$ are negatively related ($\Sigma \downarrow$ as $\mu \uparrow \Rightarrow$ negatively skewed)

Solutions for inner problem: low $\mu$, high $\Sigma$

\begin{equation}
arg\inf\limits_{(\mu, \Sigma) \in U_1(\mu, \Sigma)} \left(w^T \mu – \alpha w^T \Sigma w \right)
\geq arg\inf\limits_{(\mu, \Sigma) \in U_2(\mu, \Sigma)} \left(w^T \mu – \alpha w^T \Sigma w \right) \quad (1)
\end{equation}

$\Rightarrow$ negative skewness is penalized by linking $U(\mu)$ and $U(\Sigma)$.

$\begin{align}
\max\limits_w \left(w^T \mu – \alpha w^T \Sigma w\right) &\geq \max\limits_w\inf\limits_{(\mu, \Sigma) \in U(\mu, \Sigma)} \left(w^T \mu – \alpha w^T \Sigma w\right)\\ &\geq \max\limits_w\inf\limits_{\mu \in U(\mu), \Sigma \in U(\Sigma)} \left(w^T \mu – \alpha w^T \Sigma w\right)\quad (2)
\end{align}$

Can anyone help me in proving the equation 1 and 2?
here the uncertain set for mu(mean) could be ellipsoid and will change the problem in second order conic problem ......and the uncertain set for the sigma(variance matrix) could be a rectangular box which will change the problem in semi definite programming problem.also we can choose some others as i mention in the comments.

Comment: here U(μ) and U(Σ) are the uncertain sets of mean and covariance.

Comment: please, type it using LaTeX - otherwise it's very hard to go through your formulas.

Comment: It can be even edited without you - but "___" I cannot understand well.

Comment: @amber -- It seems this was cut-and-pasted from some homework? Please check that I've typeset correctly. Without some more info, I can't make this out.

Comment: Now I think that the previous time it was even better )

Comment: @Gortaur -- +1, I think you're right! Maybe she can take a pic and we can tweak. We can always revert if I've lost something.

Comment: @richardh....thanks richardh.....actually its not homework its my research work for phd.....here T is the transpose.....other things r ok...i will be thankful..if someone guide me...thanks

Comment: @Gortaur I just approved your edits.  Thanks for improving it!

Comment: @Shane, you're welcome :) if there is a possibility to use \DeclareMathOperator?

Comment: @Amber - please elaborate more on what is $U$ and how can be interpreted $\inf\limits_{\mu\in U(\mu)} $ - wih respect to which set is taken an infimum?

Comment: the uncertain sets are given as follow:.........................U(μ) = {μ | |μi - δi| ≤ εi} → QP...... U(μ) = {μ | μ = δ+Pu | |u|2 ≤ q} → SOCP......... U(Σ) = {Σ | –δI ≤ Σ – Σ0 ≤ δI} → QP ............................U(Σ) = {Σ | ΣL ≤ Σ ≤ ΣH} → SDP

Comment: plz someone reply me

Comment: plz put an information abour uncertain sets inside the question (press **edit**) and *explain* please what is the problem. It's really very difficult to understand what you have written ((

Comment: Gortaur can we discuss this problem face to face.....if u can tell me ur available time ...i am in Korea South so may be we have to decide the time first?if possible for u...thanks

Comment: Is the question "please solve my assignment  for next week..." really related to research in quantitative finance?

Comment: @amber The purpose of StackExchange isn't to have private conversations. We advocate open answers so that everyone here can learn. As @Gortaur states, it's difficult to understand what you're asking for. So consider editing your question to clarify what you want to know.

Answer (score 3):

@amber -

As a general hint: try to solve a small-scale case first. Pick a two- or better three-asset $(\mu,\Sigma)$ and construct the objectives. Construct the "skewness tensor" (it's not a matrix, you can think of it like a "cube" or something - consult [this book](http://goo.gl/eLTcz) on how you can actually represent it as a matrix, or [Fabozzi et al's textbook](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0471699004,descCd-google_preview.html) for an accessible discussion to the whole idea of introducing skewness tensors).

In your case, actually, it will be difficult to construct the feasible sets, since you don't seem to have a clear grasp of the optimization problem - there are many calls for clarifications. Try to spell them out explicitly.

Next, note that the skewness tensor alters *both* the feasible sets *and* the objective. It is easy to establish the monotonicity, once the tensor is explicitly introduced in both. To do so, you can even use the simple Karush-Kuhn-Tucker conditions.

Both inequalities are very easy to establish.

Good luck with your thesis.